# Excluding prefix in ObjectListing results Java client for S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket with following hierarchy:

```
bucketName
    folder1
       file1
```

I wanted to get all the files from folder1. I tried to do following:

```
ObjectListing ol = s3Client.listObjects("bucketName", "folder1"); 
List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = ol.getObjectSummaries();
```

The problem is that summaries contains `folder1/` and `folder1/file1`. Where as I was hoping to get just `folder1/file1`.

Looking around at the internet, I also tried following:

```
ListObjectsRequest req = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketBucketName("bucketName").withPrefix("folder1/").withDelimiter("/");
```

But this time I got no results back for `getObjectSummaries` call. When I remove `withDelimiter` from above I get both `folder1\` and `folder1\file1` back.

Is there any way to just get `folder1\file1` back?

Answer (score 7):

Use `withPrefix` and `withMarker` together:

```
ListObjectsRequest req = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("bucketName").withPrefix("folder1/").withMarker("folder1/");
```

This works because first you filter `withPrefix` and obtain all folder1/* keys, including folder1/, and then with `withMarker("folder1/")` you specify to get the keys that are lexicographically after "folder1/" as documented in the [javadoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html):

> The list will only include keys that occur lexicographically after the marker.

Furthermore, if folder1 contains other subfolders, you can get the direct children only, using `withDelimiter`:

```
ListObjectsRequest req = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("bucketName").withPrefix("folder1/").withMarker("folder1/").withDelimiter("/");
```

This works because the delimiter "/" makes all subfolders to be rolled up to "folder1/" but you ignore this result with the marker. The javadoc says for `withDelimiter`:

> Gets the optional delimiter parameter that causes keys that contain the same string between the prefix and the first occurrence of the delimiter to be combined into a single result element (...). The most commonly used delimiter is "/", which simulates a hierarchical organization similar to a file system directory structure.

--

In any case, `folder1/` is only listed because you surely created it through the web console. If you don't create folders directly but put objects programmatically, like `put folder2/file2` the folder won't be actually created as an independent object and so it cannot be listed.

Comment: It ended up returning all the folders with their contents that were at the same level. So for ex., if there was `folder2` at the same level as `folder1` then it returned `folder2` as well. Anyways, I ended up using, `FileNameUtils.getName()` to filter out `folder1` from the results set.

Comment: @test123, doing this you will get all the folders from the s3 location. And you are then filtering it. Which i think is not a feasible solution. 

In my case I would want to get all files in folder1 but not from folder1/subfolder1. Is there any way to do it directly while fetching the s3objects