# Mounting S3 Bucket with EC2 Instances using JAVA AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

Hi Cloud Computing Geeks,
Is there any way of mounting/connecting S3 bucket with EC2 instances using JAVA AWS SDK (not by using CLI commands/ec2-api-tools). I do have all the JAVA sdks required. I successfully created a bucket using Java AWS SDK, now further want to connect it with my EC2 instances being present in North Virginia region. I didn't find any way of to do it but I hope there must be some way.

Cheers,
Hammy

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Amazon S3 isn't a filesystem, although there are libraries out there that make it look like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "mount S3 buckets", they don't work that way for they are not filesystems. [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is a service for key-based storage. You put objects (files) with a key and retrieve them back with the same key. The key is merely a name that you assign arbitrarily and you can include "/" markers in the names to simulate a hierarchy of files. For example, a key could be `folder1/subfolder/file1.txt`. For illustration I show the basic operations with the java sdk.

First of all you must set up your amazon credentials and get an S3 client:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("your_accessKey", your_secretKey");
AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

Store a file:

```
File file = new File("some_local_path/file1.txt");
String fileKey = "folder1/subfolder/file1.txt";
s3client.putObject("bucket_name", fileKey, file);
```

Retrieve back the file:

```
 S3ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = s3client.getObject("bucket_name", fileKey).getObjectContent();
```

You can read the InputStream or you [can save it as file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream).

List the objects of a (simulated) folder: [See my answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981658/excluding-prefix-in-objectlisting-results-java-client-for-s3/15989227#15989227).